# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index -- Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

## creates the k - fold analysis

```
from scipy.stats import itemfreq
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy as np
import pickle
from csv import reader
from scipy.stats import itemfreq
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from astropy.extern.ply.cpp import xrange

seed = 0 # number of cough classes = 2; (DISEASE/NORMAL) or (COPD/CHF)
np.random.seed(seed) # generates random numbers
X_train = [] # creates training set using .csv file
Y_train = [] #creates training set using patients
X_test = [] # creates testing set using .csv file
Y_test = [] # creates testing set using patients
Z = [] # splits data
label = [] #labels split data
eps=1e-7
set_probs = [] #predicts probability
i = 0; # uses to go through all patients
correct = 0;
DISEASE = 1;
NORMAL = 1;

for i in xrange (1,10): # goes through all 9 patients
    Z.append(DISEASE)
    DISEASE = DISEASE + 1;
    label.append(1); #labels data as 1, if = DISEASE

for i in xrange (1,10):
    Z.append(NORMAL)
    NORMAL = NORMAL + 1;
    label.append(2); #labels data as 2, if = NORMAL

add = 0
add1 = 0
add2 = 0
print(len(Z))


kf = KFold(n_splits = 10, shuffle = True) 
for train, test in kf.split(Z):
    X_train = []
    Y_train = []
    X_test = []
    Y_test = []
    set_probs = []

    # Z_train - creates training set from split data
    # Z_test - creates testing set from split data
    # label_train - labels Z_train data
    # label_test - labels Z_testing data

    # This where I am getting the error
   Z_train, Z_test, label_train, label_test = Z[train], Z[test], label[train], 
   label[test]

# training set
for z in xrange(0, len(Z_train)):
    if label_train[z] == 1: # if predicted 1 = DISEASE
        mypath = '~/Users/awindmon/Documents/DISEASE_Example/';

    if label_train[z] == 2: # if predicted 2 = NORMAL
        mypath = '~/Users/awindmon/Documents/NORMAL_Example/';

# testing set
for z in xrange(0, len(Z_test)):
    if label_test[z] == 1:
        mypath = '~/Users/awindmon/Documents/DISEASE_Example/';

    if label_test[z] == 2:
        mypath = '~/Users/awindmon/Documents/NORMAL_Example/';

   clf = SVC (kernel = 'linear', random_state = 0, gamma = 1, C = 1, 
   probability = True)

   clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
   filename = 'LinearSVM_Model.sav'
   pickle.dump(clf, open(filename, 'wb'))
   count = 0

   probability_list = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
   p0=0
   p1=0
   p2=0
   p3=0
   p4=0
   p5=0
   p6=0

for  l in range(0,len(probability_list)):
    if (l!=0) and (l%3 == 0):
        set_probs.append([p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6])
        p0=0
        p1=0
        p2=0
        p3=0
        p4=0
        p5=0
        p6=0

    p0=p0+ probability_list[l][0]
    p1=p1+ probability_list[l][1]
    p2=p2+ probability_list[l][2]
    p3=p3+ probability_list[l][3]
    p4=p4+ probability_list[l][4]
    p5=p5+ probability_list[l][5]
    p6=p6+ probability_list[l][6]

    if (l == len(probability_list)-1):
        set_probs.append([p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6])
        p0=0
        p1=0
        p2=0
        p3=0
        p4=0
        p5=0
        p6=0

    print (set_probs,Y_test)

    add1=add1+clf.score(X_test, Y_test)

    print (add1/10)
```

I am new to python and I have developed this code to do k-fold cross validation for a machine learning problem. On the last line, I am attempting to divide and label my training and testing data, but I keep getting this error: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

Comment: Is the body of `for` empty, or did something go wrong with the indentation? You have to indent all the code by four spaces, for example by clicking on `{}` in the gui.

Comment: Yes. In my actual code, everything after the for is indented by four spaces. Forgot to do that when I copied it to this question.

Comment: What is the value of Z?

Comment: Z was previously defined as an array that ranges from 1-10.

Comment: @Zev If this is some standard class from `sklearn`, one should probably mention it in the question, or at least tag the question accordingly. Without any context, the question seems unclear.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I agree. I submitted an edit with that in mind.

Comment: I added the rest of the code to reduces any confusions.

Comment: Don't get discouraged that your first question was downvoted. Learning to ask clear questions that provide enough without too much info is a skill you'll develop. To help improve this question, you should mention and tag sklearn. I submitted an edit it but I think it was lost in an edit you made. If my answer helped you past this issue (ignoring other issues that you may have also hit) please select and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

The values `train` and `test` are np arrays. You probably want to do something like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np

kf = KFold(n_splits = 10, shuffle = True)
Z = [i+1 for i in range(10)]
for train, test in kf.split(Z):
    X_train = []
    Y_train = []
    X_test = []
    Y_test = []
    set_probs = []
    Z_train = np.array([Z[i] for i in train])
    label_train = np.array([label[i] for i in train])

    Z_test = Z[test[0]]
    label_test = label[test[0]]
```

The split gives you what indexes you are picking so you can use that index to get the value or the label in a similar manner.

This goes beyond the scope of this question but how you are using Z_train doesn't make sense to me because you are just using its length rather than its values. Perhaps you mean `for z in Z_train:`

Comment: I tried this, but not sure what to do with label_test and label_train. I also added the entire code to the question, if you want to take a look.